# Installing fonts on CentOS from the /tmp/ folder

Tags: fonts, centos7, fontconfig

I am trying to create a process on a machine that can asynchronously download and install fonts for LibreOffice to use. Our processes for whatever reason cannot access the `usr` folder, and every guide to installing fonts mentions to first move the file to a subdirectory in `/usr/share/fonts/`. Is it possible to install them from `/tmp`? Here is what I have tried:

1. Create a folder `/tmp/fonts`
2. Download the `Lato-Black.ttf` into that folder
3. Run the following commands:

```
os.system('chmod -R a+r /tmp/fonts/')
os.system('chmod a+x /tmp/fonts/')
os.system('fc-cache -rfv /tmp/fonts/')
```

Separately I have a process that runs the following bash:

`'while :; do echo ___; ls /tmp/fonts; fc-list; sleep 60; done'`

This process shows that the font is downloaded to the tmp folder, but the `fc-list` command is not showing Lato as one of the installed fonts. Any idea what may be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you add /tmp/fonts to the list of searched directories in the config file. The config file might be in:

```
   /etc/fonts/fonts.conf
   /etc/fonts/fonts.dtd
   /etc/fonts/conf.d
   $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fontconfig/conf.d
   $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fontconfig/fonts.conf
   ~/.fonts.conf.d
   ~/.fonts.conf
```

[More info](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html)